# Formula to determine total coin combinations problem?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This question was asked in an aptitude test and was meant to be solved within 2-3 minutes.I know how to solve it by Bruteforce method, but its time-consuming.So, is there any strategic way/shortcut to solve this type of questions?

```
You have enough coins of 1, 5, 10, 25 paise. How many combinations are possible to make 50 paise?
```

Another popular variant of this question:  `Given some dollar value in cents (e.g. 200 = 2 dollars, 1000 = 10 dollars), find all the combinations of coins that make up the dollar value. There are only penny, nickel, dime, and quarter. (quarter = 25 cents, dime = 10 cents, nickel = 5 cents, penny = 1 cent)`

Comment: Are you familiar with generating functions?

Comment: only with ordinary functions

Answer (score 1):

Brute force doesn't seem so bad for a 2-3 minute time limit.  Make a tree; each node is labeled with the amount of money you have left; levels correspond to types of coins used, and the children at a given level correspond to using a given number of that type of coin.  We want to count the number of leaves.

```
50
| [# of quarters]
50                       , 25          ,0 (1)
| [# of dimes]             |
50,  40, 30, 20, 10, 0     25, 15, 5
(11) (9) (7) (5) (3) (1)   (6) (4) (2)  <-depending on # of nickels used
```

Numbers in parentheses are the leaf counts below the given nodes.  Adding them up gives $49$ ways of making change for $50$ "paise."

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Using multinomial theorem,
Find the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{50})(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+\cdots+x^{50})(1+x^{10}+x^{20}+\cdots+x^{50})(1+x^{25}+x^{50})$$
The coefficient will be the total number of possible combinations.
This can be simplified further by the formula of sum of geometric series and by using binomial theorem.
$$\frac{1-x^{51}}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1-x^{11}}{1-x^5}\cdot\frac{1-x^{6}}{1-x^{10}}\cdot\frac{1-x^{3}}{1-x^{25}}$$
I believe you can take it from here?

Comment: I know about binomial theorem but don't know how to deduce combinations from your last term.

Comment: Apply binomial theorem for negative index. You can write $\frac{1}{1-x}$ as $(1-x)^{-1}$